# How to make InvariantCulture recognize a comma as a decimal separator?

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point

How do I parse `1,2` with `Single.Parse`? The reason of asking is because, when I am using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` I don't get 1.2 as I would like, but rather 12.

Shouldn't "Invariant Culture" ignore the culture?

[Consider the following example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UDYMYU):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Single.Parse("1,2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Console.WriteLine(Single.Parse("1.2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        float value;
        Console.WriteLine(Single.TryParse("1,2", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value));
        Console.WriteLine(Single.TryParse("1,2", out value));
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

The output of this will be

> 12
>   1.2
>   False
>   True
>   12

But I was expecting:

> 1.2
>   1.2
>   True
>   True
>   1.2

[Based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743469/system-convert-tosingle-problems-1-5-vs-1-5) [on](http://www.csharp-examples.net/iformatprovider-numbers/) [my](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/parsing-culture-invariant-floating-point-numbers/) [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059587/c-sharp-float-to-string-conversion-decimal-separator-problem) of `InvariantCulture` I should get that result, however I am not.

Comment: `var single = float.Parse("1,2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR"));`

Comment: Well I'll join in: `var single = float.Parse("1,2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-NL"));` Basically, `InvariantCulture` uses `.` as a decimal separator. `Single.Parse` doesn't ignore it, but `,` *isn't* a decimal separator in `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @Default It uses a fixed culture which happens to use `,` as a decimal separator. Any culture which uses `,` will do. The important thing is that the *user*'s culture is *not* used.

Comment: @hvd - if I then move to a culture which uses the other decimal separator, how would I then handle the *other* separator? Should I really need to use three cultures (my current, one that uses `.` and one that uses `,`) just to parse the decimal correctly..? That seems very.. bulky..

Comment: @Default You need to decide what format your strings are in. If they always use a period, use `InvariantCulture`. If they always use a comma, use a different (but still fixed) culture. If they may contain either, you've got a problem: you cannot determine whether 1,000 represents one, or one thousand.

Comment: oh, now I get it! so `Parse` parses the `,` as a thousand separator! That explains the current behavior. Quick question (or I'll just try it myself), would a culture with no thousand separator then be able to parse both `,` and `.` as the decimal separator?

Comment: @Default I don't think so, but I'm not entirely sure. But even cultures that don't *use* a thousands separator do normally *have* a thousands separator that can be used when parsing.

Comment: @Default But if you can guarantee that you will *never* have a thousands separator, you can easily call `string.Replace` to change all commas to periods before parsing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` uses `.` as a decimal separator, and `,` as a thousands separator. This is independent of any user settings, and independent of the string you've got, hence the name "InvariantCulture". The specific details are listed on the [`NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo.aspx) MSDN page.

To use `,` as the decimal separator, don't use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Instead, use a culture that does use `,` as the decimal separator. There are many that would suit your needs.

Alternatively, create a custom culture based on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. You can call its [`Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to create a copy of which you can modify the properties.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `InvariantCulture` uses `.` as a decimal separator? I am (fairly) sure that the thousand separator will not be used, so a `string.Replace` would be "safe" (as you mentioned in comment). Replacing the Thousand separator in a cloned CultureInfo doesn't seem to do any difference when parsing.

Comment: @Default Yes, the `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` page I linked to mentions that the values won't change, and mentions that the example program outputs "`NumberDecimalSeparator          .`". Combine those two and you can be fairly certain that it will not face changes.

Answer (score 5):

One of articles you've linked says "The invariant culture is internally associated with the English language". So 'InvariantCulture' doesn't mean "try to match any culture". It means: Ignore the local system culture settings and treat this number as formatted in specific standard (basically: English culture standard). 
So if you want to handle different formats, your options here are:

1. Try parsing the number without specyfing culture (will use local OS culture info), then try with InvariantCulture, then maybe try some fallback culture you expect the number to be formatted with.
2. Replace ',' with '.' and parse the number string using Invariant culture. You may want to make sure that the number string does not contain decimal group separators (like 1,000.00).