# Conversion of String to Double is not right

Tags: c#, .net, culture

I am trying to parse doubles infering from a string with the following code:

```
double.TryParse(contractResult.Result.ValueWithDiscount, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ValueWithDiscount);
double.TryParse(contractResult.Result.DebitValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out Value);
```

But for some reason it is not working. I have two servers that have different configurations from each other. And one is Parsing a `"0.5"` to `0.5` but the other is parsing to `5`.

I also tried to use:

```
double.TryParse(contractResult.Result.DebitValue, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out Value);
```

But then the server that was parsing correctly started to parse to `50` instead of `0.5`. Any tip of why it is happening?

Update - Values using the following code:

```
NumberFormatInfo loNumberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
loNumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
loNumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
double ValueWithDiscount = 0.0;
double.TryParse(contractResult.Result.ValueWithDiscount, NumberStyles.Any, loNumberFormatInfo, out ValueWithDiscount);    
logger.Log("ValueWithDiscount: " + contractResult.Result.ValueWithDiscount);
logger.Log("ValueWithDiscount Parsed: " + ValueWithDiscount);
```

**Server that works:**

```
ValueWithDiscount: 0.50
ValueWithDiscount Parsed: 0,5
```

**Server that does not work:**

```
ValueWithDiscount: 0,5
ValueWithDiscount Parsed: 5
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer but I once had a similar problem that turned out to be the location settings and different regions using . or , for decimals.

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? you can use [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) for example.

Comment: On the machine that doesn't work, are you **100% sure** that the string is `0.5`? Could it, perhaps, be `0,5`? Can you show us where `contractResult.Result.ValueWithDiscount` is populated?

Comment: @mjwills on the machine that does not work the value is 0,5

Comment: I have added an update with the log information.

Comment: see this question for reference as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375160/how-to-make-invariantculture-recognize-a-comma-as-a-decimal-separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always use a "." as decimal separator you can use a fix FormatInfo to convert.

```
NumberFormatInfo loNumberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
loNumberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
loNumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";

double ldOut;
double.TryParse("0.5", NumberStyles.Any, loNumberFormatInfo, out ldOut);
```

Update:

If your string contains "." and "," you can replace "," before convert.

```
string lsNumber = "0,5";
lsNumber = lsNumber.Replace(",", ".");
```

Comment: will give a try ;)

Comment: it converted to 5.

Comment: Are you sure that the value "0.5" parse to "5"?

Comment: I have added an update with the log information using the code you provided. Basically it is happening the same as my initial code.

Comment: You see, that your string (I think `contractResult.Result.ValueWithDiscount` is a string) once it's "0.5" and once it's "0,5" that is not the same. Maybe you can replace "," with "." in your string before convert.

Comment: will try that solution

Comment: it worked, please post your answer so I can accept :)

Comment: Update my answer