# DataGridTextColumn in Datagrid don't accept comma on updating source of binded variable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, .net-4.8

I created Datagrid in my WPF project and binded `ItemsSource` with object that contains `double` type variable `amount`. I binded `DataGridTextColumn` with `amount` variable and used `UpdateSourceTrigger` to update it on any change by setting it to `PropertyChanged` (I really need this). Problem is, by typing for example `3,5`, after source update value is changing to `35`. When I'm typing `3.5`, after update it stays as `3.5`.

What I tried?

- Changing `CultureInfo` in whole `Thread` and `UIThread` to `InvariantCulture`.
- Checking my current OS region, by default it should use comma, not dot.

I have no idea, what problem is here.
It's WPF project on .NET Framework 4.8. OS is Windows 10 and IDE is latest Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Depending on UI culture, you work either with comma or dots. if UI thread set as for example EN then it will accepts dot, if you set as DE, then it will accepts comma. You might need a workaround or converter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make InvariantCulture recognize a comma as a decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375160/how-to-make-invariantculture-recognize-a-comma-as-a-decimal-separator)

Comment: @Ugur `InvariantCulture` was wrong choice, I admit it. But using my local region culture, even if it uses comma, doesn't accept comma in my app. 
@Đøharrrck Only proved that using `InvariantCulture` was wrong. But using OS culture with comma is not making any change for app.

Comment: @GhostVolume, but how do you use your local culture. You you should be changing your default culture, where your start your application.

Comment: @GhostVolume: Try to set the `Language` property of the `DataGrid` to a culture that actually accepts a comma as the decimal separator: `<DataGrid ...Language="sv-SE" />`

Comment: @mm8 Thank you, it helped. I wouldn't think there is `Language` property for `DataGrid`. I posted it as answer and mentioned you. I'm grateful.

Comment: @GhostVolume: I posted an answer myself in case you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Language` property of the `DataGrid` to a culture that actually accepts a comma as the decimal separator, e.g.:

```
<DataGrid ...Language="sv-SE" />
```